# A widget picking items from a very long list in Plone

Tags: plone

I have a z3c.form based form where there is one ordered selection list with few possible choices to be chosen from very, very, large set.

Does there exist any special widget for such purpose in Plone world? I assume sites with a lot of categories would need similar widget.

Autocomplete and/or special scrolling of long list would be features I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
 - https://github.com/collective/collective.z3cform.widgets

I think the TokenInputFieldWidget is what you are looking for.